# Cómo guardar varias imágenes al mismo tiempo en firebase usando la cámara de fotos con ionic y angular

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic

¿Cómo puedo guardar varias imágenes en firebase al mismo tiempo? Este código, lo que se hace es cada vez que tomas una foto con la cámara , se genera un array de imágenes (img), pero al dar click en upload solo se guarda una imagen, como podría hacer para que se guarden todas las imágenes generadas,

Código completo y detallado:

```
captureDataUrl: string;
alertCtrl: AlertController;

capture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 50, 
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options)
      .then((imageData) => {
       
    // imageData es una cadena codificada en base64 o un URI de archivo
      // Si es base64:
        
        this.captureDataUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        this.imagesArray.push(this.captureDataUrl);
      }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
      
    });
  } // fin de capture camera


  upload() {
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      // Crea una marca de tiempo como nombre de archivo
    
    const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    // Crea una referencia a 'images / todays-date.jpg'
    
    const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);

    imageRef.putString(this.captureDataUrl, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)
      .then((snapshot)=> {
        
         
      });
  }
```

el componente html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of imagesArray;">
       <img src='{{i}}' /> 
  </ng-container>

 <ion-button ion-button (click)="capture()"> toma una foto!</ion-button>
 <ion-button ion-button (click)="upload()"  >subir a firebase!</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay un método para subir varias imagenes a la vez. Lo que debes hacer es un bucle que recorra el array de imagenes

```
upload() {
    this.imagesArray.forEach(image => {
        firebase.storage().ref(`images/${Date.now()}.jpg`)
            .putString(image, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL);
    });
}
```

Comment: sigue guardando una imagen, algun otra idea?.. a imageArray lo tengo como public imagesArray: Array<any> = new Array<any>(); igual se agradece por contestar

Comment: tal vez es porque le está dando el mismo nombre a todas

Comment: exelente , como guardaria el nombre en cloud firestore,

Comment: No habias mensionado nada de firestore. De ser así podes usar el id de firestore como nombre de la foto. Es mejor eso que un timestamp porque incluso sin dividir el `Date.now()` puede ser que aveces se repita el nombre

Comment: gracias.........